# find variable as selector in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got 2 dynamic feeds with dynamically generated feed item id's. The goal is to hide and show elements of 2nd feed on 1st feed click. Code follows. I get "Unexpected token )" error in console, on the line that is supposed to show the item. Still can't figure out why. Php code works fine. Checked js vars with alerts. They work fine too.

HTML code

```
<div class="faq-deskbox clearfix">
    <div class="fleft faqdeskindex">
       <div class="faqlistitem" id="fq<?php echo $current_post_id ?>">
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fleft faqqdeskinfo">
       <div class="faqcontitem" id="afq<?php echo $current_post_idb ?>">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

related css

```
.faqcontitem {display:none;}
.faqcontitem:first-child {display:block;}
```

and jquery

```
$(".faqdeskindex .faqlistitem").each(function(){
    var fqid = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".faqcontitem").hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find("#a" + fqid +).show();
        });
});
```

Comment: `fqid +)` <-- unexpected token

Comment: Question can be closed I think...

Comment: Not sure i'm following. How is it supposed to go without bracket closed?

Comment: @archibib: You have the `+` operator after `fqid`, but there is no second operand for it. Instead you have `)`, which is the unexpected token. Remove the `+` after `fqid`.

Comment: i'm trying to use a variable there

Comment: Javascript does not support partial application, so `fqid +` is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("#a" + fqid +).show();
```

You seem to have added an additional trailing `+`. Javascript did not expect to see another `+` operator, so it raised an "Unexpected token" error.

Changing `("#a" + fqid +)` to `("#a" + fqid)` should fix the issue.

Comment: that worked. thanks!